# NSButton background color is faded

Tags: swift, appkit

I have an NSButton and I am trying to set the background color to a solid blue. However, setting it to `NSColor.blue.cgColor` only gives me this faded blue. Every color I try always gives me a faded version. My code:

```
let loginButton: NButton = NSButton()
loginButton.wantsLayer = true
loginButton.isBordered = false
loginButton.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
```

[image]

For context, this view is inside a sidebar. It is a descendent NSView of an NSSplitItem. I am using NSSplitViewController. Any view rendered outside the sidebar has no problem rendering the correct colors. How can I make this button have a solid blue background?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still relevant, but I was looking for a solution myself.

I was using an `NSButton` checkbox and it showed a lighter gray text and not the normal black text for the label. Only during checking the button, when it changed to its highlighted state, the text was shown in black.

After a lot of trial an error, I remembered that `NSSplitViewItems`s with `NSSplitViewItem.Behavior.sidebar` are using a different `NSAppearance`, namely [`NSAppearance.Name.vibrantLight`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsappearance/name/1535233-vibrantlight).

The appearance which is used by child views, and by that, also the button, is usually based on the result of [`effectiveAppearance`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsappearancecustomization/1535147-effectiveappearance), which seems to be something like `self.appearance ?? parent.effectiveAppearance`.

So setting the button appearance to the current app default changes its appearance to be as expected:

```
loginButton.appearance = NSApp.effectiveAppearance
```